# how do i align text in kivymd button?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

i need to halign text in kivymd button to the left and i found solutions for default kivy like text_size: self.size and halign='left', is button still a label in kivymd like in kivy? If no then how do you align text inside it?

Comment: Yes, `MDTextButton` does inherit the label. But I guess the alignment part is hardcoded. I'm not sure though

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
text_align:'center'